# QueryDSL cannot execute registered function

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, querydsl, amazon-aurora

I'm using MySQL8.0(Actually, it's Amazon Aurora database) with Spring boot/QueryDSL.

I want to execute `UUID_SHORT()` function declared in MySQL.

But When I execute `UUID_SHORT()` function with `JPAQueryFactory`, it throws exeption.

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode
```

And this is my source code.

```
public class MyRepository extends MySQL8Dialect {
  ...

  // Register unregistered database function(in this case, 'UUID_SHORT')
  public MyRepository() {
    super();
    registerFunction("uuid_short", new NoArgSQLFunction("uuid_short", StandardBasicTypes.STRING);
  }

  public String getUuidShort() {
    // Case 1. Native query works
    return entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT uuid_short()")
      .getSingleResult()
      .toString();

    // Case 2. JPAQueryFactory doesn't work
    return jpaQueryFactory.select(Expressions.stringTemplate("uuid_short()"))
      .from(myEntity)
      .fetchOne();

    // Case 3. JPAQueryFactory with already registered function in MySQLDialect.class works
    return jpaQueryFactory.select(Expressions.stringTemplate("sysdate()"))
      .from(myEntity)
      .fetchOne();
  }
}
```

Why this happens?

Comment: [UUID_SHORT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short) output datatype is BIGINT UNSIGNED (unsigned 64-bit integer, not string).

Comment: I've tried `StandardBasicTypes.BIG_INTEGER` with `Expressions.numberTemplate(Long.class, "uuid_short()")`. But it didn't work too. Thrown exception was same.